# CDF of independent variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am given two independent variables $X$ and $Y$. Where $F_X(x)=F_Y(x)=x^4 \ 0\le x \le 1$.
I am looking for CDF of $Z=max(X,Y)$ and $E(Z^2)$

I need some pointers, especially for $Z^2$.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $Z\le z$ if and only if $X\le z$ and $Y\le z$. For $0\le z\le 1$, this probability is $(z^4)^2$. Thus $F_Z(z)=z^8$ on $(0,1)$. For completeness, note that $F_Z(z)=0$ if $z\le 0$ and $F_Z(z)=1$ for $z\ge 1$.

Now we know that $Z$ has density $8z^7$ on $(0,1)$, and can calculate $E(Z^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Completing Nicolas answer:

We have $Z≤z$ if and only if $X≤z$ and $Y≤z$. Hence, for $0≤z≤1$: $F_Z(z) = P(Z ≤ z) = P(max(X,Y)\leq z) = P(Y \leq z \cap X\leq z) = P(Y \leq z)P(X \leq z) = F_X(z)F_Y(z)=(z^4)^2 = z^8 $

Short: $F_Z(z) = z^8$ if $0<z<1$, $F_Z(z)=0$ if $z≤0$, and $F_Z(z)=1$ if  $z≥1$.

Consequently Z has density $f(z) = 8z^7$  on $(0,1)$ and $E(Z^2) = \int_0^1 z^2 * 8z^7 dz = 8\int_0^1 z^9 dz = 8(\frac{1}{10}*1-\frac{1}{10}*0) = \frac8{10}$